# Button - Voucher onclick

Tags: html, css, onclick, popup, less

Hello community need some assistance,

I am trying since couple days to add into exit-popup template one php button which onlick interacts with less template and adds Voucher code into the cart.

I got no success yet, if someone could assist me. Could possibly award somehow :)

Theoreticly its could even be possible to inject into sql onlick instead of injecting to element.

[Github Original cart_footer.tpl](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.2/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/checkout/cart_footer.tpl)

[Github Original Voucher.tpl](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/5.2/themes/Frontend/Bare/frontend/checkout/items/voucher.tpl)

Platform: **shopwaredemo.de/**
and any item to cart, so you can see elemnts

So far i have done:
Form:

```
<form method="post" action="{url action='addVoucher' sTargetAction=$sTargetAction}">
<div class="popupbanner">  
<a href="#" class="myButton" clickon="copyToClipboard('#p2');ImportVoucher('FREE16')" > 

<div class="close-exit-intent" title="Click to Copy" type="submit">
    <input id="p2" class="p22" value="FREE16" />
    <p id="p2" class="p22">FREE16</p>
    </div> </a> 
<p class="click2copy">Click to Copy ↗</p>  
<a href="#" class="modal-footer"><p>No thanks</p></a>
</div>
</form>
```

Copytoclipboard js

```
function copyToClipboard(element) {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val($(element).text()).select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove();
}
```

ImportVoucher js

```
function ImportVoucher(element) {

    $('input[type=p2]').click(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings('input[type=p2]').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#sVoucher').val($('.selected').val());
    $temp.remove();
}
```

added id into cart-footer

```
<input type="text" class="add-voucher--field is--medium block" id="sVoucher" name="sVoucher" placeholder="{"{s name='CheckoutFooterAddVoucherLabelInline'}{/s}"|escape}" />
```